# Hosting laravel 5.6 on VPS?

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-5.6, maatwebsite-excel

hi guys am trying to host a laravel 5.6 app on a VPS for the first time and i cant seem to get it right..am using LEMP.i followed some guide which was using php 7.0 but my project requires php 7.1 "i think i managed to resolve the error using the following line"

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-cli php7.1-fpm php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mysql 
php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-curl
```

now am getting the following error

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.1 -> satisfiable by 
phpoffice/phpexcel[1.8.1].
- phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.1 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension 
xml is missing from your system.
Problem 2
- phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.1 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension 
xml is missing from your system.
- maatwebsite/excel 2.1.28 requires phpoffice/phpexcel ^1.8.1 -> satisfiable 
by phpoffice/phpexcel[1.8.1].
- Installation request for maatwebsite/excel 2.1.28 -> satisfiable by 
maatwebsite/excel[2.1.28].
```

this is my first time so any useful information is very welcome :)

Comment: The error message is quite clear `... requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing...`

Comment: You are missing `php-xml` on your php installation. You should install and enable it. Try `sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to install the php-xml package. You can do it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

When the package is installed run the composer install again.

You can read more about this issue here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-do-i-install-the-dom-extension-for-php7

edit:
if it does not install the correct version of the package, you can use the command from @Dharma Saputra's comment:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```